# Apache 2 - Mod rewrite is installed and active but I can't get it to work... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Mod Rewrite is activated an enabled as far as I can tell (I followed the tutorial to install it and activate it using a2enmod rewrite).

I'm trying to set up some pretty URLS using PHP - prettymuch I want:

mysite.com/sites/mysite/blog/article-title-here/

instead of mysite.com/sites/mysite/blog/index.php?article=article-title-here

I'm following [Nettuts tutorial here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/) to the letter.  (the Using PHP portion anyway)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

I've even looked at some of the Questions with similar titles and tried following the solutions for them as well, but I just get the standard 404 still.

I'm pretty new to the whole server admin thing and am learning as much as I can through a low cost naked VPS. It's challenging and fun, but this has me pulling my hair out.

Comment: Look at the server's error log to see what it's trying to access (it'll log the full file path) and not finding to cause that 404. Possibility: remove the `.` in your rewriterule, so it's just `/index.php`.

Comment: To check if mod rewrite is enabled, in any PHP page, preferably a new one, put in <? phpinfo(); ?> and save it. then look for loaded modules, this should have mod_rewrite listed if it is working, if it's not working then you will need to probably get the module again per your OS instructions and then try to enable it again

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Apache section rather than PHP if possible.

Mod rewrite is one of those bits of code that is much more complex than would be seen at face value to it is worth looking at a few tutorials/examples/references when coding it to make sure that you haven't missed something important under your usage.

This code is based on minimum requirements based on your question, these happen to be my minimum requirements for the site I have implemented it for and if there are other variables you may need to adjust it to suit. E.g. other variables in the URL string will need to be added and changing the path.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^sites/mysite/blog/([^/]*)$ ./index.php?article=$1
```

Here is [another reference](http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/116/seo-friendly-urls-with-mod-rewrite/) that may help you.

I hope this helps :-)